# Drop down with MySQL and PHP sample

Tags: php, forms

I have tried out this example but not sure where I have gone wrong - I've created the database and relative fields. When I select UK it gives me a blank result. Here is my script

main.php

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
$dbselect=mysql_select_db("test");
$sql_country = "SELECT * FROM COUNTRY";
$result_country = mysql_query($sql_country) or die("Query problem");

echo "<form method='POST'>";
echo "<select name='country' onChange='get_cities(this.value)'>"; //get_cities is defined below
echo "<option value=''></option>";
while($row_country = mysql_fetch_array($result_country))
{
echo "<option value='".$row_country['id']."'>".$row_country['country']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='city' id='city'></select>"; //We have given id to this dropdown
echo "</form>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_cities(country_id)
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "cities.php", /* The country id will be sent to this file */
beforeSend: function () {
$("#city").html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
},
data: "country_id="+country_id,
success: function(msg){
$("#city").html(msg);
}
});
}
</script>
```

cities.php

```
<?php
// Code for cities.php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
$dbselect=mysql_select_db("test");
$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];

$sql_city = "SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE country_id = '".$country_id."'";
$result_city = mysql_query($sql_city);
echo "<select name='city'>";

while($row_city = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
echo "<option value='".$row_city['id']."'>".$row_city['city']."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

?>
```

Sample code: http://www.x-developer.com/php-scripts/loading-drop-downs-with-ajax-php-and-fetching-values-from-database-without-refreshing-the-page

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Note also that `$country_id` is being injected into a SQL statement without untainting. This will permit anonymous users to run arbitrary SQL statements on your database, which is a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any error checking in your example, and you should be aware that with databases, plenty of things can go wrong!

Try making these amendments. Change this:

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

to:

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
```

And this:

```
$result_country = mysql_query($sql_country);
```

to:

```
$result_country = mysql_query($sql_country) or die("Query problem");
```

This will highlight two common problems - connecting or not finding the specified table.

---

Also, `cities.php` doesn't appear to connect to the database at all. Add in the `mysql_connect` and the `mysql_select_db` from the first file into the second, and that should connect it correctly.

---

Lastly, there is a serious security vulnerability with this tutorial, which would permit internet users to run arbitrary SQL on your database server. Change this:

```
$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];
```

to this:

```
$country_id = (int) $_REQUEST['country_id'];
```

That will force the country ID to be an integer, rather than just accepting it uncritically as a string.

Comment: I have added in the connect but to no success.Please check the post i have editted it.

Comment: Try accessing `http://host/cities.php?country_id=X` directly in your browser, where 'host' and 'X' are your local web server and country code respectively. Do you get an error?

Comment: (I've updated my answer with a security vulnerability in the tutorial as well).

Comment: I have done the test http://host/cities.php?country_id=X it works could it have to do with the javascript?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Check the AJAX operation in your browser - there's native toobars in Chrome and Safari, or use Firebug in Firefox. Make sure the response looks like HTML, and that there are no PHP errors, and that the status code is 200.

Comment: I have tried on different browsers. If there are other referrences i cna try that does the same functions as the example that would be some great help. dynamic dropdowns

Comment: Persist with this one now, you are nearly there. What does "I have tried with different browsers" mean - what have you tried? Is your AJAX op being shown as working?

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server contains a dropdown menu, but the current code appends the HTML result not into a div or span, but into into another dropdown menu, thus:

```
<select name='city' id='city'><select name='city'>....</select> </select>
```

This is incorrect. To avoid this, change:

`echo "<select name='city' id='city'></select>";`

to

`echo "<div id='city'> </div>";`

Or, remove`echo "<select>"` line from cities.php

```
<?php
// DB CONNECTION
$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];

$sql_city = "SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE country_id = '".$country_id."'";
$result_city = mysql_query($sql_city);


while($row_city = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
echo "<option value='".$row_city['id']."'>".$row_city['city']."</option>";
}



?>
```

Comment: For the benefit of the OP, can you explain in your question why this would help?

Comment: @halfer I want to select a value then it will populate the second drop down box. In the example provided in the link on the post takes values in a database in this instance take the COUNTRY value is UK and in the second dropdown it will show London and Bristol in from the cities DB.

Comment: responce from server will contains dropdown menu, but you append result not into some div or span, you insert response html into another dropdown menu <select name='city' id='city'><select name='city'>....</select> </select> this is solution (P.S. use firebug or other debug tools)

Answer (score 0):

In your `cities.php` there is no database connection. Write the DB connection there also after that it will give you drop down.

Comment: I have added in the connect no success.Please check the post i have editted it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not any databse connection in `cities.php`, so `SELECT` statement does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use jquery, which is a great help when it comes to ajax driven web apps,
Try this for your jquery code

```
//ensure the select name 'country' has the id 'country'
$("#country").change(function(){
//get country id of the selected country option
var countryid = $("#country option:selected").val();
//here we post the id of the country to the php page. note that within the curly braces, the first parameter is what corresponds to the variable in php e.g $countryid=$_POST[country_id]. The second parameter is the javascript variable
$.post("cities.php",{country_id:countryid},function(data){
//check that the json object returned is not empty
if(!$.isEmptyObject(data))
       { 

     var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        var cityid = [data[i].id];
        var cityname = [data[i].city];      
        html += '<option value = '+cityid+'>'+city+'</option>';

    }
//append the results of the query. The prepend part is to make a blank option first and make it selected so as to force a user to actually select a city.
       $("#city").html(html).prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>").show();

        }   

        else{
             alert('No cities found for this country');
            }

},'json')
})
```

Your php page for cities remains as it is but make the following adjustments

```
<?php
// Code for cities.php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
$dbselect=mysql_select_db("test");
//change it from request to post.
$country_id = $_POST['country_id'];
//the below code is not safe!!! You are open to sql injection. To make it worse you are connected as root. A malicious user can drop your database. 
$sql_city = "SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE country_id = '".$country_id."'";
$result_city = mysql_query($sql_city);

while($row_city = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
$data[] = $row_city;
}
//return the json onject to the client.
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

The above code might help you should you choose the jquery way of writing javascript. You will need to download jquery first.